# Gulp and typescript : node.d.ts doesn't compile

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, gulp, tsd

I currently have a problem with typescript. I am trying to use follow a simple tutorial (http://blog.edenmsg.com/angular2-typescript-gulp-and-expressjs/) about constructing a server with express. 
So I followed the inscructions and used tsd to install express. And then I tried to launch a gulp build as described in this file :

gulpfile.js

```
/**
 * Created by alicia on 10/03/2016.
 */
var gulp = require('gulp');
var path = require('path');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var del = require('del');
var concat = require('gulp-concat')
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

// SERVER
gulp.task('clean', function(){
    return del('dist')
});

gulp.task('build:server', function () {
    var tsProject = ts.createProject('server/tsconfig.json');
    var tsResult = gulp.src('server/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ts(tsProject))
    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(concat('server.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});

// CLIENT

/*
 jsNPMDependencies
*/
var jsNPMDependencies = [
    'angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
    'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
    'rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
    'angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js',
    'angular2/bundles/router.dev.js'
]

gulp.task('build:index', function(){
    var mappedPaths = jsNPMDependencies.map(file => {return path.resolve('node_modules', file)})

    //Let's copy our head dependencies into a dist/libs
    var copyJsNPMDependencies = gulp.src(mappedPaths, {base:'node_modules'})
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/libs'));

    var copyCss = gulp.src('client/css/**/*.css')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));

    //Let's copy our index into dist
    var copyIndex = gulp.src('client/index.html')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    return [copyJsNPMDependencies, copyCss, copyIndex];
});

gulp.task('build:app', function(){
    var tsProject = ts.createProject('client/tsconfig.json');
    var tsResult = gulp.src('client/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ts(tsProject))
    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/app'))

});
var typescript = require('gulp-tsc');

gulp.task('compile', function(){
    gulp.src(['client/**/*.ts'])
        .pipe(typescript())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
});

gulp.task('build', function(callback){
    runSequence('clean', 'build:server',
        'build:index',
        'build:app',
        callback);
});

gulp.task('default', ['build'])
```

Every task compiles (clean, build:index...) except for build:server.
This is the error that I get :

```
[12:07:43] Starting 'build:server'...
server/typings/node/node.d.ts(1759,52): error TS1005: '=' expected.
server/typings/node/node.d.ts(1760,76): error TS1005: '=' expected.
server/typings/node/node.d.ts(1761,52): error TS1005: '=' expected.
server/typings/node/node.d.ts(1761,96): error TS1005: '=' expected.
server/typings/node/node.d.ts(1771,54): error TS1005: '=' expected.
server/typings/node/node.d.ts(1772,74): error TS1005: '=' expected.
server/typings/node/node.d.ts(1773,54): error TS1005: '=' expected.
server/typings/node/node.d.ts(1773,94): error TS1005: '=' expected.
```

Apparently the problem is coming from node.d.ts. I really have no idea why it is not working even though it is the version found on Definitely typed. 
Would you have any idea on how to help ?

Edit : I also include my tscongig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declaration": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/browser.d.ts",
    "typings/browser"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your gulp task to:

```
gulp.task('build:server', function() 
{
    var tsProject = ts.createProject('server/tsconfig.json');

    var tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())   
        .pipe(ts(tsProject));  

    return tsResult.js.pipe(concat('server.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))        
});
```

And make sure that you exclude node_modules in tsconfig using 'exclude' section like in this example:

```
{ 
    "compilerOptions": { 
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true, 
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "commonjs", 
        "target": "es6",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "declaration": false,
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/browser.d.ts",
        "typings/browser"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I tried it, and changed my tsconfig.json file (and included it in the post up there).
I also changed the build:server function. But I still have the exact same problem. I even tried to re-import tsd and all. But it still gives out the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I updated my package.json file to include all the latest versions (for most cases, some required older versions since they were dependencies in others and newer version are not yet supported). This is how my final package.json file looks like:

```
"dependencies": {
  "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.17",
  "es6-promise": "3.2.1",
  "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
  "express": "4.13.4",
  "gulp-concat": "2.6.0",
  "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
  "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
  "systemjs": "0.19.29",
  "zone.js": "0.6.12",
  "typescript": "1.8.10"},
"devDependencies": {
  "del": "2.2.0",
  "gulp": "3.9.1",
  "gulp-concat": "2.6.0",
  "gulp-sourcemaps": "1.6.0",
  "gulp-typescript": "2.13.5",
  "run-sequence": "1.2.1"}
```

From my research I can infer it had something to do with the typescript and gulp version used on the example not been supported anymore. Hope this helps you out Licia.